# Text vertically not center in any tag

Tags: css

I'm using the font `Calibre` and the font is not aligned with any tags such as `button`, `p`, etc.

I played with height and nothing worked. Any idea what could be the reason for this?

[image]
[image]

Let em know if you need any other details

Code:

```css
button{
 font-family: 'Calibre';
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 background: green;
}
```

```html
 <button>Sign Up</button>
```

There's no other code or css in this codebase. I just started a fresh project and this is the only code I wrote there.

**PS**: This is not a duplicate of any other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css)

Comment: Please post your code as well as what you have tried

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that question. It is an entirely different issue. See the selection of the text. It is not vertically aligned in the selection. The text is aligned vertically center for the button. But not for the text selection area and hence causing misalignment.

Comment: @DanielBeck This is not a duplicate question. It's an entirely different question.

Comment: @user1012181 I doubt that is the related CSS as in the snippet the button doesn't look the same color and shape wise.

Comment: Try the flexbox-based answer in the linked potential duplicate: I've had luck with using that in correcting font-specific misalignment, even in cases where line-height doesn't work.

Comment: the is a font issue, we cannot control the selection area. The font is made like that. So either use another font, contact the font developer or consider hacks with line-height/padding until you get the needed behavior

Comment: Seems like it's a font issue

Answer (score 0):

Ah, don't we love CSS?

if your HTML is like this:
`<button><span>Sign Up</span></button>`

Try messing with the styling of the inner text element (`<span>`) with `vertical-align: middle`, `align: center`, and maybe add some padding like `padding-top: 5px`. You could also change `line-height: 80%` to close up that 'gap' of extra space below the characters within it's area.

Answer (score 0):

Center text vertically within a button with flex:

```
<button class="btn"> Text </button>

.btn {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

For inline/inline-block elements, they might have vertical-align values that are different from the text.